# Access violation 0xc0000005 rendering multiple objects

Tags: go, opengl, 2d

Recently I have been toying with open-gl eventually I decided to give it a shot and write my very own straightforward 2d-game engine myself, unfortunately for some reason when attempting to render multiple animatable sprites I end up with an access violation 0xc0000005 exception which seems to be originating from Cgo open-gl bindings. I provide all of the code necessary to reproduce the problem below. I tried to comment it as much as I could in order to make it easier to parse. I would be more than happy to receive any form of guidance because I honestly fail to understand why it occurs and does not seem to be able to find any resources online addressing the issue.

more important third-party imports;

```golang
"github.com/go-gl/glfw/v3.1/glfw"
"github.com/go-gl/mathgl/mgl32"
"github.com/go-gl/gl/v4.1-core/gl"
```

the main loop;

```golang
func main() {
    window := new(Window)
    window.NewWindow(wsize, wheight)
}
```

the window.NewWindow function;

```golang
func (w *Window) NewWindow(width, height int) {
    if err := glfw.Init(); err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("failed to inifitialize glfw:", err)
    }
    defer glfw.Terminate()

    glfw.WindowHint(glfw.ContextVersionMajor, 4)
    glfw.WindowHint(glfw.ContextVersionMinor, 1)
    glfw.WindowHint(glfw.OpenGLProfile, glfw.OpenGLCoreProfile)
    glfw.WindowHint(glfw.OpenGLForwardCompatible, glfw.True)
    window, err := glfw.CreateWindow(width, height, "Primitive renderer", nil, nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    window.MakeContextCurrent()

    if err := gl.Init(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    w.Handle = window

    vs, err := NewShaderFromFile("./shaders/basic.vert", gl.VERTEX_SHADER)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fs, err := NewShaderFromFile("./shaders/basic.frag", gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    p, err = NewProgram(vs, fs)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    p.Use()

    gl.Disable(gl.DEPTH_TEST)
    gl.Enable(gl.BLEND)
    gl.BlendFunc(gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)

    // set orthographic projection:
    projection := mgl32.Ortho2D(0, float32(wsize), float32(wheight), 0)
    prUniformLocation := p.GetUniformLocation("projection")
    gl.UniformMatrix4fv(prUniformLocation, 1, false, &projection[0])

    // 2d sampler:
    spUniformLocation:= gl.GetUniformLocation(p.handle, gl.Str("tsampler\x00"))
    gl.Uniform1i(spUniformLocation, gl.TEXTURE0)

    // generate a quad (generates vao, vbo, ebo):
    quad := NewBuffer(quad, indices)

    // load textures for a given object;
    t1, err := NewTextureFromFile("./textures/x.png", gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }


    trUniformLocation := p.GetUniformLocation("transformation")


    for !window.ShouldClose() {
        glfw.PollEvents()

        // background color;
        gl.ClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
        gl.Clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)

        // bind the quad buffer;
        gl.BindVertexArray(quad.vao)

        // paint 5000 quads:
        for i := 0; i < 5000; i++ {
            transformation := mgl32.Translate3D(32, 32, 1)
            transformation = transformation.Mul4(mgl32.Scale3D(32, 32, 1))
            gl.UniformMatrix4fv(trUniformLocation, 1, false, &transformation[0])

            gl.BindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, t1[0].handle)
            gl.DrawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, 6, gl.UNSIGNED_INT, gl.PtrOffset(0))
        }

        gl.BindVertexArray(0)
        window.SwapBuffers()
    }
}
```

the NewTextureFromFile function

```golang
func NewTexture(img image.Image, wrapR, wrapS int32) []*Texture {
    rgba := image.NewRGBA(img.Bounds())
    draw.Draw(rgba, rgba.Bounds(), img, image.Pt(0, 0), draw.Src)
    if rgba.Stride != rgba.Rect.Size().X*4 {
        fmt.Printf("Unsupported stride\n")
    }

    // number of textures generated;
    h := make([]uint32, 5)
    gl.GenTextures(5, &h[0])

    target := uint32(gl.TEXTURE_2D)
    internalFmt := int32(gl.SRGB_ALPHA)
    format := uint32(gl.RGBA)
    pixType := uint32(gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE)
    dataPtr := gl.Ptr(rgba.Pix)

    var rtextures = make([]*Texture, 0)
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        gl.BindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, h[i])
        defer gl.BindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0)

        gl.TexParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_R, wrapR)
        gl.TexParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, wrapS)
        gl.TexParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR)
        gl.TexParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR)

        row, column := i%12, int(math.Floor(float64(i/12)))
        gl.PixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, int32(rgba.Rect.Size().X))
        gl.PixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_SKIP_PIXELS, int32(32*row))
        gl.PixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_SKIP_ROWS, int32(32*column))
        gl.TexImage2D(target, 0, internalFmt, 32, 32, 0, format, pixType, dataPtr)
        gl.PixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, 0)
        gl.PixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_SKIP_PIXELS, 0)
        gl.PixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_SKIP_ROWS, 0)

        gl.GenerateMipmap(h[i])

        t := &Texture{
            handle: h[i],
        }
        rtextures = append(rtextures, t)
    }

    return rtextures
}
```

shaders;

```
vs:
#version 410 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 text_coord_in;
uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 transformation;
uniform vec3 colors;

out vec2 text_coord;
out vec3 colors_fs;

void main() {
    colors_fs = colors;
    text_coord = text_coord_in;
    gl_Position = projection * transformation * vec4(position, 1.0);
}

fs:
#version 410 core
out vec4 color;
in vec2 text_coord;
in vec3 colors_fs;
uniform sampler2D tsampler;

void main() {
    color = texture(tsampler, text_coord);
}
```

```
Exception 0xc0000005 0x0 0x12d8 0x5d37c839
PC=0x5d37c839

runtime: unknown pc 0x5d37c839
stack: frame={sp:0x388fe28, fp:0x0} stack=[0x0,0x388fe80)
000000000388fd28:  000000000388fd80  0000000000428310 
[...]

callstack:
goroutine 1 [syscall]:
github.com/go-gl/gl/v4.1-core/gl._Cfunc_glowUniformMatrix4fv(0x5d37c830, 0x100000001, 0x3f80000000000000, 0xc0003f4040)
        _cgo_gotypes.go:21291 +0x4c
github.com/go-gl/gl/v4.1-core/gl.UniformMatrix4fv(...)
        C:/Users/x/go/src/github.com/go-gl/gl/v4.1-core/gl/package.go:12659
main.(*Window).NewWindow(0xc000081f78, 0x12c, 0x12c)
        C:/Users/x/go/src/github.com/a/index.go:216 +0xa6f
main.main()
        C:/Users/x/go/src/github.com/a/index.go:44 +0x5b
rax     0x0
rbx     0xc000425c48
rcx     0x1
rdi     0xc000425c48
[...]
```